# Angular JS: bind class to two different expressions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-class

I have an angular bootstrap tabset.

**NOTE**:  this is a ui-bootstrap directive.  So ng-class does not work.

To be able to change the class conditionally, I found here on SO:

```
  <tab heading="My Tab" class="{{classifyForm.$dirty ? 'tab-dirty':''}}">
```

Works great, when the form `classifyForm` is dirty, it adds the class `tab-dirty` and otherwise removes it.

Except now I need to do the same thing with another condition and another class in *addition* to what I have.

What is the way to combine the two expressions, so I get essentially:

`if form is dirty,tab-dirty` (what I have now) **and** `if foobar then tab-foobar`

so, if the form is dirty and foobar is true, the resulting tab should have both `tab-dirty` and `tab-foobar` classes, if only one is true then only have that one class.

Comment: I would create a method in the controller to generate the classes string, perhaps with arguments :)

Comment: That's a good approach.  There might not be any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very annoying that you can't use ng-class on this but you can do the following

```
<tab heading="My Tab" class="{{ (classifyForm.$dirty ? 'tab-dirty ':'') + (classifyForm.foobar ? 'tab-foobar ':'')}}">
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how to structure something like that.  Thanks.

Comment: It works.  I use the same kind of thing in my application.

Comment: I had to make n edit to ensure the added classes all have a space between them.  Otherwise, in the above case  you'd  have gotten `class="tab-dirtyfoobar"`

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: `ng-class` won't work on the angular ui `tab` directive like the OP mentions. Here is the link to one of logged bugs: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1741

They don't offer any good solutions to get around it. So the only way I see is making a function in the controller to handle the logic to apply the class(es).

For all other cases (where possible), you should use `ng-class`

```
<tab heading="My Tab" ng-class="{ 'tab-dirty': classifyForm.$dirty, 'your-other-class': someOtherProperty }">
```

Comment: I cannot use ng-class, this is a directive fro ui-bootstrap.  If I could use ng-class, it would be as easy as you suggest.

Comment: Can you make a plunker for it? That's strange why `ng-class` wouldn't work.

Comment: "Tab" is a directive and the directive actually writes out its own bootstrap html code and transcludes its contents. Whoever created it did not allow for ng-class to be added.  This is an older version of the directive, 0.13.1.  Perhaps the current one is smarter, but this project is stuck in the old one.